# GPGPU, OpenCL, CUDA, ATI Stream

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, ati

Please tell me what technologies GPGPU exist already and which hardwares vendor's implement GPGPU?

I've been reading articles on various sites from morning and I've become confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AMD-ATI` allows you to harness the power of GPU using a language based on `Brook+`.
And `nVidia` provides `CUDA`.

Comment: Do you known something about Intel implementetion of GPGPU in Larrabee?

Comment: Ya..I heard about it few years back that Intel is going to come up with Larrabee (hybrid between CPU and GPU). Not sure if they ever actually came out with that project (http://www.electronista.com/articles/10/09/20/larrabee.graphics.impractical.hungry.says.intel/)

Comment: @Matias - not completely, although it looks like there won't be a 'Larrabee' product per-se. But this past summer Intel announced 'Knight's Ferry' and 'Aubrey Isle', which appear to be the current follow-up projects using some of Larrabee's ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Brook and CUDA are proprietary technologies. And OpenCL is industry standard, now supported by ATI and NVIDIA. ATI even provides CPU-based implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that **Intel** is going to create  architecture with name **Intel Larrabee**
and **VIA** declared about  creating **VIA Trinity** , both of which can be use in future for **GPGPU** and can be as competitor for **nVidia CUDA** and **ATI Stream**.